# How do you place "is" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm having difficulty constructing this sentence in terms of "is". Which one of these is correct or is there another way of constructing the sentence?

> a first-class “machine” that is tuned for
> the Chinese market and is capable of producing superior outcomes.

> a first-class “machine” that is tuned for
> the Chinese market and capable of producing superior outcomes.

Context: machine refers to a company.

Comment: As the two phrases describing the 'machine' are rather different, I think it reads better with _is_ repeated.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical, so there is no "correct" answer in this sense.  Personally, I would choose the one without the repeating "is" (unless I want to maximize my word count).